# Is there a standard way to add presentation information to Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Let's say I have a Vue component that has the following data, which has been retrieved from an API:

```js
data: () => ({
    books: [
        {name: 'The Voyage of the Beagle', author: 'Charles Darwin'},
        {name: 'Metamorphoses', author: 'Ovid'},
        {name: 'The Interpretation of Dreams', author: 'Sigmund Freud'},
    ],
}),
```

I would like to store **presentation** variables for each of these books, e.g. an *open* boolean to determine whether the book is open or not. I don't want the API to return these variables though, as I don't want the API to be cluttered with presentation data.

Is there a standard way of doing this in Vue?

Comment: When you say `store`, you mean in the localStorage of the browser, So that next time the user opens the app, the app knows which book was open ?

Comment: @DavidAlvarez no, it doesn't have to be persistent between page reloads. Just general variables that are responsible for the *visual* aspect of the objects.

Comment: Then I would do exactly as @Andres Foronda suggests in his answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add the presentation data after receive the information from the API:

```
...
data: () => ({ books: [] });
...
methods: {
  // API call to get the books
  async requestBooks() {
    // TODO: add try catch block
    const books = await getBooks(); // Your API call
    this.books = addPresentationInformation(books);
  },
  addPresentationInformation(books) {
    return books.map(book => {
      return {
        ...book, // default format from API (name, author)
        open: false, // add the open variable to the object
        reading: false,
        currentPage: 0
      }
    });
  }
},
created() {
  this.requestBooks(); // Call the api on created hook to initialize the books data prop
}
```

You can add many presentation variables as you want, I recommend use vuex to store the books and their presentation variables, that way you can save information in the local storage for each book, so after restart the app, you can know if some book is currently being reading or is open.

Answer (score 0):

I would personally maintain another array that contains some state relational to each book rather than trying to mutate the API response data. That's just me though.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Since your answer is referring to another answer, it should probably have been a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Probably another way is to copy object and modify it and keep original response data

```js
data(){
    let data = Object.assign({}, this);
    // add necessary presentation data
    return data;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I now use [normalizr](https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr) to process and flatten responses from the backend API, and this library provides a means to add extra data. For example, the following `schema` adds the `hidden` data attribute.

```js
const taskSchema = new schema.Entity(
    'tasks',
    {},
    {
        // add presentation data
        processStrategy: (value) => ({
            ...value,
            hidden: false
        }),
    }
);
```